# Magento2.3.1 : No.of files increased

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.1, multi-website, core-file-storage

When I tried to open my website, I am getting the error that **There has been an error processing your request**

Then I checked in system.log.

The error is **Disk quota exceeded**

[image]

The no.of files count make doubled to the original files count when i deploy the content.

**Note:** I have a single Magento installed website only.

**Why that much of files existed in Magento?**

Comment: Magento auto generate some of file like in var/cache, generated folder files.

Comment: you probably have the smallest shared hosting package...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The above-listed answers are also might be helpful.
But, In my case, I got the solution from our hosting provider Godaddy.

The issue is, so many emails have come to our webmails. One email is considered as one file.

That's the reason, The available count of the file storage gets crossed to the given limit as we have one lakh+ emails.

I have removed those all unused emails.

Now the issue is resolved and the website is working fine.

Comment: Good to hear that you resolved it. +1 :)

Comment: hm, the question was about  `Why that much of files existed in Magento?`

Comment: @MagenX, Yes, The reason behind which exists. And the answer is explaned why that much much of files existed. Please read the answer and question completely dear.

Comment: great tool to check what is taking space on disk is console tool - ncdu , its showing directory and file usage in tabel. Can be very helpful in issues like this one.

Comment: @MagenX, Can you give a more explanation about your comment dear?

Answer (score 5):

Magento generates files in following directories

- generated
- var
- pub/static
- pub/media/catalog/products/cache (In most cases this directory takes most of the storage)

The no of files you have uploaded at start would surly increase after Magento generates all other files.

You need to manually check directory sizes in each of the above listed directories by command, something like this:

```
cd var/
du -sh
```

Comment: hm, how is `If you have other OS like centOs then directory size check command would be different.`  ?? what are you talking about??

Comment: I mostly worked on ubuntu, and I am good with ubuntu commands. I am also familiar with centOs, I have seen different commands for both OS. But after your comment, I have checked `du` command, it's same on both OS. Thanks for sharing knowledge. Updating my answer :)

Answer (score 4):

When Magento compiles (di compilation and static content deploy) it takes a lot of the already existing files in the `app/code/` directory, or vendor directory, and produces a lot of generated and cached content in the `generated/` and `var/` directories.

File caching will also generate a large number of files, try to cache using Redis instead if you don't already